# Parsing an Options Object to a List of Options

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

I have been working on a small library against an JSON-based API.  This library makes use of an "options" object, a series of key-value pairs that specify advanced behaviour:

```
{
  "id": 1234
  ...
  "options": {
    "notify_no_data": True,
    "no_data_timeframe": 20,
    "notify_audit": False,
    "silenced": {"*" :1428937807}
  }
}
```

I've represented the options concept in Haskell using a list of options:

```
data Option = NotifyNoData NominalDiffTime -- notify after xyz
            | NotifyAudit -- notify on changes
            | Silenced (Maybe UTCTime) -- silence all notifications ("*") until xyz (or indefinitely)

newtype Options = Options [Option]
```

Implementing `toJSON` was simple enough; I instantiated `toJSON` for the `Option` type, and then used those as helpers for the `Options` type.

```
instance ToJSON Option where
  toJSON (Silenced mtime) =
    Object $ Data.HashMap.fromList [("silenced", mapping)]
    where stamp = maybe Null (jsonTime . floor . utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds) mtime
          mapping = Object $ Data.HashMap.singleton "*" stamp
  toJSON (NotifyNoData difftime) =
    Object $ Data.HashMap.fromList [("notify_no_data", Bool True)
                                   ,("no_data_timeframe", stamp)]
    where stamp = jsonTime $ floor (difftime / 60)
  toJSON NotifyAudit =
    Object $ Data.HashMap.fromList [("notify_audit", Bool True)]

instance ToJSON Options where
  toJSON (Options options) = Object $ Data.HashMap.unions $ reverse $ (opts:) $ map ((\(Object o) -> o) . toJSON) options
    where opts = Data.HashMap.fromList [("silenced", Object Data.HashMap.empty)
                                       ,("notify_no_data", Bool False)
                                       ,("notify_audit", Bool False)]
```

The problem I am running into is in the `fromJSON` implementation for `Options`.  All the use cases I've seen before supply a fairly simple json-object-representation to data-representation mapping.  What I need to do is convert an object to an object of options to a list of data (Option) representations.  For example, the sample JSON under "options" that I gave at the start would have to become:

```
Options [NotifyNoData 20, Silenced (Just (posixSecondsToUTCTime 1428937807))]
```

`FromJSON` requires an implementation of `parseJSON :: FromJSON a => Value -> Parser a`.  I am having trouble understanding how to build a Parser using this optional object structure given by the API.  Is there a standard approach to parsing a JSON object to a list like this?  It may be that I am failing to fully understand the `Parser` typeclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maybe use the parser monad to extract all the information, something like:

```
parseJSON (Object v) = do
      maybeNotify <- v .:? "notify_no_data"
      maybeTimeFrame <- v .:? "no_data_timeframe"
      let nots = case (maybeNotify,maybeTimeFrame) of
                   (Just True,Just stamp) -> [NotifyNoData $ fromJsontime stamp]
                   _ -> []
      return $ Options nots
```

(fromJsontime is just a helper function to convert from the JSON value to your NominalDiffTime, I suppose you have something for that).

Do the same for the other types of options, concatenating the result.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [json-stream](https://github.com/ondrap/json-stream) parser (which I am the author of), it would look like this (from my head, untested):

```
option =     NotifyNoData      <$> "no_data_timeframe" .: value
                               <*  filterI id ("notify_no_data" .: bool)
         <|> const NotifyAudit <$> filterI id ("notify_audit" .: bool)
         <|> Silenced          <$> "silenced" .: "*" .:? value

optionList = Options <$> toList option
```

The code expects you have FromJSON instance for UTCTime (or you could just use 'integer' and some kind of fromposixtime etc.).